# Exchange Transport Agent Bounce MailItem

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010, exchange-transport-agents

In our Exchange `RoutingAgent`, we would like to be able to bounce an email back to the sender in the event of an unexpected exception. We would also like to be able to send the bounce message to some pre-defined admin email too if possible. Is there any way to bounce a message in the `OnSubmittedMessage` or the `OnResolvedMessage` events? I am hoping there is some method in the Exchange libraries to easily achieve this, or is there some way to create a new MailItem and send it to the original sender and possibly an admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate a new message to do that there is a sample for this on https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mstehle/2010/03/10/howto-return-to-sender-transport-agent-sample/

You should also be able to use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj976002(v=exchg.150).aspx

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Do you know the best way to determine if I'm processing is a DSN/bounce back message, I need to be able to avoid an infinite loop? I see the `Message.MapiMessageClass` property, which has a value of "Report.IPM.Note.NDR" but I'm not really certain if this is reliable.

Comment: I always add a custom header into any message processed or created this both prevents a loops but it also prevents you processing the item multiple time when it pass though different hub servers. Otherwise you can parse through the Mime Headers to determine the type.